# Firebase Realtime Database retrieving data issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database for storing and retrieving data for my Android application. On my home screen I have implemented  **addListenerForSingleValueEvent** for reading from my database.My database has one value for example :

```
 "version" : 455
```

> After listening from my leaf "version" i retrieve value "455" in my app correctly. Now i perform two steps :
>
> - Kill the app.
> - Manually update leaf from firebase console to 467.

After that when i launch the app i get the same old value "455" for the first time , on second launch i get the updated value "467".

Is this proper behaviour for firebase database ? Is there anyway i can get updated value from the first app launch ?

**EDIT :** Adding Code

```
  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  DatabaseReference ref= database.getReference();
  database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
  ref.keepSynced(true);
  ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot != null) {
          long version = (long) dataSnapshot.child("version").getValue();
          // This is the value which doesn't update for the first time.
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
  });
```

**P.S.** : I have used ***ref.keepSynced(true);*** , still for the first time after updating manually gives the old value.

Comment: Please share the code that provides you this behaviour.

Comment: @AlexMamo added the code !

Comment: @AndréKool :  Edited it , persistanceEnabled and keepSynced(true) doesn't have any effect on the outcome.

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Your code is correct. Have you tried to comment `keepsynced(true)`? What is the behaviour?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks , commenting the same worked from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your code I can say that contains no error. To solve the problem, just comment the following line of code:

```
database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
ref.keepSynced(true);
```

And your problem will be solved. Your data will be displayed for the fist time.

Comment: Just accepted your edit suggestion. It's ok now?

Comment: Yeah fine now :)

Comment: not working for me i have try it

Comment: @ShakeelAhmed Please post a fresh new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.